# A href in innerHTML using concatenation

Tags: javascript

I looked at the other answer for putting an a href in via innerHTML but could not get it to work in my particular example.

I'm trying to add the linked word "mission" but keep getting the error "Unexpected identifier".

```
function myFunction(){
    //Select Paid Membership Text under Level
    var str = document.getElementById("pmpro_levels_table").innerHTML;
    var res = str.replace("Paid Membership", "$1 monthly to fund our ");
    //replace text
    document.getElementById("pmpro_levels_table").innerHTML = res + "<a href='"simpledmedicines.com/mission/"'>mission</a>";
}
myFunction();
```

The part I think I'm not doing right is:

```
document.getElementById("pmpro_levels_table").innerHTML = res + "<a href='"simpledmedicines.com/mission/"'>mission</a>";
```

Specifically:

```
.innerHTML = res + "<a href='"simpledmedicines.com/mission/"'>mission</a>";
```

Comment: `.innerHTML = res + "<a href='"simpledmedicines.com/mission/"'>mission</a>";`

Should be:

`.innerHTML = res + "<a href='simpledmedicines.com/mission/'>mission</a>";`

Comment: When I try this, it creates the link properly, but it puts the linked word mission on a separate line, is it possible to keep it as part of the same sentence?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can offer you slightly different solution if you are interested.

```js
function myFunction(){
    //Select Paid Membership Text under Level
    var str = document.getElementById("pmpro_levels_table").innerHTML;
    var res = str.replace("Paid Membership", "$1 monthly to fund our ");
    //replace text

    const table = document.getElementById("pmpro_levels_table");
    table.innerHTML = res;
 
    // create anchor element
    const anchor = document.createElement('a');
    // set anchor href attribute
    anchor.setAttribute('href', 'simpledmedicines.com/mission/');
    // set anchor text
    anchor.textContent = 'mission';
    // append anchor to your table
    table.appendChild(anchor);

}
myFunction();
```

Comment: When I try this I get the error:
Uncaught ReferenceError: a is not defined
    at myFunction (<anonymous>:13:5)
    at <anonymous>:21:1

Comment: @Kaiya oops I used wrong variable name, should be ok now

Comment: <thead> <tr> <th>Level</th> <th>Price</th> <th>&nbsp;</th> </tr> </thead> <tbody> <tr class="odd"> <td>Free Membership</td> <td> <strong>Free</strong> </td> <td> <a class="pmpro_btn pmpro_btn-select" href="https://simplemedicines.com/membership-account/membership-checkout/?level=1">Select</a> </td> </tr> <tr class=" active"> <td><strong>$1 monthly to fund our </strong></td> <td> <strong> </strong>. </td> <td> <a class="pmpro_btn disabled" href="https://simplemedicines.com/my-account/">Your&nbsp;Level</a> </td> </tr> </tbody> mission

Comment: @Kaiya can you put your whole code into fiddle, and give me a link?

Comment: @Kaiya I think I know where the problem was. Try the updated version.

Comment: Here's my attempt to fiddle this wordpress page, but couldn't replicate the error in the fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/tyrannon/rycc1tmz/

This is the actual page for the site:
https://simplemedicines.com/membership-account/membership-levels/

Comment: thanks, that last update fixed it. Although it places the link on a separate line in what appears to be a separate div.

Comment: @Kaiya Then the problem must be in your styling. Anchor is an inline element therefore something else must be pushing it to the new line.

Comment: @Kaiya I have looked at that page, where exactly do you want to put that anchor (mission)?

Comment: I would like it to read:
$1 monthly to fund our mission on just one line

Answer (score 0):

You just need to remove the double quotes from your anchor tag. See this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o5o8u0eu/) and the updated code below:

```
<div id="pmpro_levels_table">
  Paid Membership
</div>
```

---

```
function myFunction(){
    //Select Paid Membership Text under Level
    var str = document.getElementById("pmpro_levels_table").innerHTML;
    var res = str.replace("Paid Membership", "$1 monthly to fund our ");
    //replace text
    document.getElementById("pmpro_levels_table").innerHTML = res + "<a href='simpledmedicines.com/mission/'>mission</a>";
}
myFunction();
```

Comment: I see that this works in the fiddle, but when I apply it to the WordPress page, it places the linked word "mission" on the next line.
https://simplemedicines.com/membership-account/membership-levels/

Comment: I don't know exactly what kind of styling you're looking for, but you can move the "mission" line up to the same line as "Membership Levels" by adding the following CSS: #fundOurMission { display: inline-block; }